# How could i add phonebook contacts to my chat app in ios by using xmpp framework and openfire server?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xmppframework

I am new to chat application and making it in objective-c. I wanted to know how could i save all my phonebook contacts as user. i know how to fetch contacts from address book but dont have much idea about xmpp framework and openfire.If anyone could help me.

Comment: Sorry for late can you please show me what you have done till now. I mean  show me  some code here.

Comment: for adding user i have done the same u have in ur post but  not showing in openfire server

Comment: where you are adding your contacts to openfire.

Comment: send your mail id i vl add you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you know how to fetch contacts.now every contact you need to add Xmpp Roaster.like below
call this method called at your contact fetching class.

`[[self appDelegate] addNewBuddyToMyAccount:tempNumber withNickName:[[tempContactList objectAtIndex:i] fullname]];`
`//in my terms tempNumber is the phone number that is JID.`

in your xmpp class follow below code to add to roster
`NSString * buddyNameJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@serverName",buddyUserID];
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:buddyNameJID];
//if you don't need permission then use below line otherwise comment
    [[self xmppRoster] acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:jid andAddToRoster:YES];
//here we are adding our contact to our roster then check once in roaster in openfire
    [[self xmppRoster] addUser:jid withNickname:nickName];`

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying but i cant see those contacts in my openfire server .. do i need to manually add dummy user over openfire server and then i have to add them as rosters?

Comment: no need first you connected to the openfire check that then above code works fine

Comment: but the code is not working for me. shall we continue discussion over chat?

Comment: @I_User yes,come to chat then it is easy for me also

Comment: i didn't find your mail.

Comment: this adds all the user in my contact to my roster. I want to only add the users that are registered in my application. Any other way to achieve this.